# How to start leanback-launchable-activity in calabash-android?

Tags: calabash-android

I have an app, there are two activities:

- **leanback-launchable-activity**:
  name='myapp.tv.activity.MainActivity'
- **launchable-activity**: name='myapp.view.MainActivity'

For tests in calabash I need start the specific activity. 
When I use device, the mobile version is started, it's ok .
But when I use TV, the TV version (Android TV) doesn't start, it's failed, because:

> `rescue in main_activity': No launchable activity found in AndroidManifest (RuntimeError)

How to start leanback-launchable activity in Android TV when I use calabash-android? Maybe I can specify the activity, which I need start?

Answer (score 0):

```
def start_test_server_in_background(options={})
    env_options = options
    env_options[:target_package] ||= package_name(@app_path)
    env_options[:main_activity] ||= main_activity(@app_path)
```

start_test_server_in_background looks for main_activity key to launch in options hash array. If you can fill that option with your desired activity name, it will pick up the updated activity

I mean call start_test_server_in_background(options) from support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb with

```
options={main_activity:'myapp.tv.activity.MainActivity'}
```